# Parse js object to query string by javascript like Sequelize query with defined template

Tags: javascript, json

I'm have issues with parser from JS Object to Query String with defined template by my self. I have JS Template like below:

```
var simpleObj = {
  $and : [
  {
    Age: {$gte: 20},
    Gender: {$eq: 0}
  },
  {
    Age: {$lte: 65},
    Gender: {$eq: 0}
  }
  ],
  $or : {
    City: { $eq: 'Singapore' }
  }
};

var Op = {
  or: Symbol.for('OR'),
  and: Symbol.for('AND'),
  eq: Symbol.for('='),
  ne: Symbol.for('!='),
  gte: Symbol.for('>='),
  gt: Symbol.for('>'),
  lte: Symbol.for('=<'),
  lt: Symbol.for('<')
};

parserJsObjectToString(obj) {
  ...
  return 'string'
}
```

Expected result when call parserJsObjectToString(obj) { ... } is a string like this

query = "((Age >= 20 AND Gender = 0) OR (Age <= 65 AND Gender = 0)) OR (City = 'Singapore')"

Please have suggestion for logic here. Thanks.

Comment: so is your question like given `op` and a `simpleObj`, you are wanting someone here to write a function that provides the expected output string?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd even build `Op` at all, but what have you [**tried yourself**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: @Jaya i'm doing it but still in finding the suitable solution to adapt with as much as possible case. write or suggestion to me about logic is always welcome.